# Eclipse Autocomplete JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE for PHP and now that I started using also JS I am missing the autocomplete options. I do not know if they're missing because I did something wrong or because the variables are not defined yet (similiar to MATLAB). Autocomplete works great with PHP, HTML and CSS but not with JS.
I tried the classic

```
> Window > Preferences > JavaScript > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced
```

and

> Installing extensions

but it did not help. I also tried to reference to some external files, but I am pretty sure that's not what is wrong.

I've been searching the whole day and I did not find an actual answer. As Eclipse has so many multiple options to adjust everything, I am getting a bit overwhelmed with that...

I would appreciate someone explaining to me how the autocompletion works. Where and whwn does it look for the suggestions (definitions in the js file or in the whole script) and why does it not show the DOM methods like window.onload or document.getElementById for example. Is this normal because there is no window/document yet or do I have to check some checkboxes in order to make eclipse do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best content assist (and validation and more) for JavaScript and all dynamic web languages is available in the [CodeMix plugin](https://www.genuitec.com/products/codemix/) for Eclipse.

[Here's a specific comparison](https://www.genuitec.com/tech/javascript-eclipse/) between Eclipse JSDT and CodeMix.

You can [install CodeMix](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codemix) from the Eclipse Marketplace here.

Hope that helps!

Comment: FINALLY ! Thank you !! so glad i got this back, was seriously considering reverting back to Aptana IDE

Comment: CodeMix is ***NOT*** a free plugin, indeed, it is expensive. You have a 45 days trial, and then you must pay for it. And it does not autocomplete javascript inside a JSP file. Is there any free plugin for autocomplete?

Comment: Alex, you're right, CodeMix isn't free, but I'd like to clarify that it's $29 a year - that's about how much you'd spend for a single cup of coffee every month. If you're a professional developer, I don't believe that's expensive at all, and if you're a student, come talk to us about educational discounts.

Adding support for JavaScript in JSPs is one of the features we're currently investigating; good to know it's a capability you find valuable.